# How can I animate my image infinitely using CSS3

Tags: jquery, css, animation, transform, transition

I have an image that has these styles:

```
<img src="images/head-tails.gif" class="graphs" />
```

```css
.graphs {
    -webkit-transition: all 2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 2s ease;
    transition: all 2s ease;
    /* -webkit-animation:animated 5s infinite; */
    /* -moz-animation:animated 5s infinite; */
    /* -o-animation:animated 5s infinite; */
    /* animation:animated 5s infinite; */
}
.graphs:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

So when I hover over the image it rotates 360 degrees, like a coin. What I would like to make though is when the page loads, the image will do this animation (the rotation) infinitely, without need to hover over my mouse. How I can make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **keyframe animation** for this. Write like this:

```
.graphs {
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -webkit-animation-name:orbit;
    -webkit-animation-duration:2s;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count:infinite;
    -moz-animation-timing-function:linear;
    -moz-animation-name:orbit;
    -moz-animation-duration:2s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes orbit { 
from { -webkit-transform:rotateY(0deg) } 
to { -webkit-transform:rotateY(360deg) } 
}
@-moz-keyframes orbit { 
from { -moz-transform:rotateY(0deg) } 
to { -moz-transform:rotateY(360deg) } 
}
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/ktPev/1/

Comment: In the link you gave me it works fine, its exactly what i want to make, but for some reason in fy file doesn't work

Comment: Ok i found out what was wrong and fixed it. Thanks! one more question please.. If I have more images with the same class, how can i make them rotate with some delay-time, so that they are not synchronized???

Comment: I think you'll need to use different classes and then use the animation-delay property to define when each animation should start. Here's and updated version of my demo below - http://jsfiddle.net/ccryz/7/

Comment: @ChristoferVilander good one but you can achieve this even less code check this http://jsfiddle.net/ccryz/8/

Answer (score 0):

Use keyframe animations instead. Uncomment the commented code and change the `animation-timing-function` to `linear`. Like this `animation: animated 5s linear infinite;`. Then define the keyframe animation, for example like this (I've used -webkit- in my example):

```
@-webkit-keyframes animated {
        to { -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg); }
}
```

and it should work!

Here's a [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ccryz/4/)